# loop failing when wrapped in try catch to run few times

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

Have this code where i am trying to run a loop for few times to make sure i do get my result, but for some reason, i am still getting an error displayed on sreen and it is not even doing the cflog so i can know what is going on, any help will be appreciated

```
var aData = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    try {
        var a = {};
        var as = calltoapitoogetdata;
        a['count'] = as;
        ArrayAppend(aData, mData);
        var retJSON = serializeJSON(aData);
        writedump(retJSON);
        //return serializeJSON(aData);
        break;
    } catch (any e) {
        i = i + 1;
        cflog(text = "Call failed #i#", application = true, file = "loogevent");
        writedump(i);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the error being displayed on the screen?

Comment: when the apicalled and api does not return right results, it displays an error and if api successds it will return json, so my take is to catch that error and let it repeat 10 times until i get the json response back from api call

Comment: You didn't answer the question: what IS the error? Please [Edit] the question to include the full error message.

Answer (score 2):

If your code is still erroring it is most likely coming from the `cflog` call being made in your `cfcatch`. If you are running a version of Adobe ColdFusion the script version would be :

`WriteLog(type="Error", file="myapp.log", text="[#ex.type#] #ex.message#");`

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/writelog.html

Lucee has made many of the CFScript functions equivalent of their tag names but with Adobe CF there are a number of functions that do not comply with this. `<cfdump> -> writeDump` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

I think troubleshooting is easier if all available information is right in front of you on the screen.  So, I would troubleshoot like this.  Your code is below with my additions in uppercase:

```
var aData = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    try {
        WRITEOUTPUT('TRY NUMBER #I# <BR>);
        var a = {};
        var as = calltoapitoogetdata;
        WRITEDUMP(AS);
        a['count'] = as;
        ArrayAppend(aData, mData);
        var retJSON = serializeJSON(aData);
        writedump(retJSON);
        //return serializeJSON(aData);
        break;
    } catch (any e) {
        i = i + 1;  // THIS LINE IS NOT NECESSARY
        WRITEOUTPUT('CATCH NUMBER #I# <BR>);
        cflog(text = "Call failed #i#", application = true, file = "loogevent");  //THIS LINE GETS REPLACED BY
        WRITEDUMP(E);
        writedump(i);  // THIS LINE GOES AWAY
    }
}
```

Comment: it just calls to 1 and then if any issue happens, it does not write a log file, just displays on screen

Comment: loop does not seems to be working once it goes into the catch statement

Comment: Continuing to say "getting an error.." or "displays on screen", but not posting the actual error, isn't very helpful since no one can actually see the error except you.  Help the folks that are trying to help you - post the error message.